# Openebs NFS and LocalPV Provisioner Pods Crash after Helm Installation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, openebs

On a homelab kubernetes on ubuntu 22.04. hosts, I want to install openebs with an nfs provisioner through:

```
helm install openebs --namespace openebs openebs/openebs --create-namespace --set nfs-provisioner.enabled=true
```

At first all the pods are running:

```
kubectl get pods -n openebs                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
openebs-localpv-provisioner-7c8ffb99f9-2xfr7   1/1     Running   0          13s
openebs-ndm-mx57f                              1/1     Running   0          13s
openebs-ndm-operator-56c5b679f7-49sgp          1/1     Running   0          13s
openebs-nfs-provisioner-74f4f7cffd-mwqh9       1/1     Running   0          13s
```

But immediately afterwards, this happens:

```
kubectl get pods -n openebs
NAME                                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
openebs-localpv-provisioner-85dd945f8b-fjjkf   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7 (47s ago)   17m
openebs-ndm-8rg56                              1/1     Running            0             17m
openebs-ndm-operator-56c5b679f7-cgwx8          1/1     Running            0             17m
openebs-nfs-provisioner-74f4f7cffd-kzdpn       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4 (73s ago)   6m31s
```

and the logs of openebs-nfs-provisioner-74f4f7cffd-kzdpn are:

```
E0417 14:44:28.621613       1 leaderelection.go:361] Failed to update lock: Put "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/openebs/endpoints/openebs.io-nfsrwx": context deadline exceeded
I0417 14:44:28.621705       1 leaderelection.go:278] failed to renew lease openebs/openebs.io-nfsrwx: timed out waiting for the condition
F0417 14:44:28.621732       1 controller.go:888] leaderelection lost
```

I can see that two endpoints are created:

```
kubectl get endpoints -n openebs
NAME                ENDPOINTS   AGE
openebs.io-local    <none>      13m
openebs.io-nfsrwx   <none>      13m
```

but they are never assigned values. Is this phenomenon familiar to anyone and is there a solution?